# c# sending Parameters through PostBackUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send parameters from one page to another using the URL. Im trying to use PostBackURL to do this but whenever I debug my variables on the other page are full of junk.

Here is my aspx code from the first page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" PostBackUrl="~/ReportingMergeCheck/Report.aspx?DateStamp='DateStamp'ReportSourceID='ReportSourceID'" runat="server">
```

Now Im trying to catch the DateStamp and ReportSourceID on the Report page. to do this im using c# code:

```
string ADate = Request.QueryString["DateStamp"];
int MYID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ReportSourceID"]);
```

unfortunately its not filling with dates or IDs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an ampersand character:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" PostBackUrl="~/ReportingMergeCheck/Report.aspx?DateStamp='DateStamp'&ReportSourceID='ReportSourceID'" runat="server">
```

Comment: Yes you are right I added it but still not really working my string ADate is still filled with "\\'DateStamp\\'"

Comment: Well you do have that literal value in the field don't you?  What value are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting the Date as say 01/02/15 in string format. I tried it without the literals but still its filling with either Eval or the literal DateStamp.

Comment: You'll need more context, then what your providing.  I can't replicate with the code I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys thanks for all the help and a special shout out to Gregs post, really helped me get to the right answer. So the problem was of course the format of my PostBackURL, in the end this was the string that worked.

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "~/ReportingMergeCheck/Report.aspx?DateStamp=" +  Eval("DateStamp","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")  + "&ReportSourceID=" + Eval("ReportSourceID") %>'
```

It has a formated date in it for people with the same problem in the future thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" PostBackUrl="~/ReportingMergeCheck/Report.aspx?DateStamp=DateStamp&ReportSourceID=ReportSourceID" runat="server">
```

Comment: Gave this a try it fill ADate with 'DateStamp'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have an issue, your issue stems from a typographic error. The lack of the ampersand (`&`).  That is actually used to separate different parameters.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbExample" runat="server" OnClick="lbExample_Click" />
```

I'm utilizing a normal event here, rather than your approach so I can use the server to build the data in my desired manner.

```
protected void lbExample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Parse any Command Arguments, or anything else to build URL.
     var url = String.Format("~/Example?id={0}&report={1}", id, report);
     Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

So you'll notice that the `?` represents the start of our parameters for the Query String, the `&` adds more parameters.  On the new page your redirecting to, you shouldn't have any problems pulling the data from the collection:

```
var id = Request["id"];
```

You shouldn't have any peculiar slashes, those slashes may be due to a incorrect escape, or data being passed.

If you follow the current approach, remove the `'` from the parameter, as that will modify the type.  You should make it:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbExample" runat="server" PostBackUrl="
    ~/ReportingMergeCheck/Report.aspx?DateStamp=DateStamp&ReportSourceID=ReportSourceID" />
```

Comment: Anytime you put things in the query string like that, you should UrlEncode them. `String.Format("~/Example?id={0}&report={1}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(id), WebUtility.UrlEncode (report);` Otherwise you can end up with odd results if the parameters have a special character such as `&` or `#`.

Comment: Hey I tried using his new code but when i try and Build I get the error    No overload for '' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: @mason True, spaced it.

Comment: Input string is not in the correct format. When I add watch it says DateTime is filled with "DateTime"